# How can I design a search query on Stack Overflow to include specific keywords?

Tags: support, tags, search

I would like to search for specific keywords within posts containing a specific tag. I designed the following query on Stack Overflow:

```
[Tag] AND "search-string 1" OR " search-string 2" OR " search-string 3"
```

I am not sure if the AND/OR is allowed since I do not receive the desired results since it incorrectly returns results for

```
[Tag] AND "search-string 1" AND " search-string 2" AND " search-string 3"
```

In fact, it is also highlighting the words **"AND" and "OR"** in the return results

How can I design the desired search query?

Comment: `OR` only works between tags, not for regular search terms.

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment! Could you suggest a workaround or hint at how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can use Google. For the "OR" query, search for `"Tag" "search-string 1" OR "search-string 2" OR "search-string 3" site:stackoverflow.com`. For the "AND" query, search for the same string after stripping every occurrence of "OR".

Comment: This SEDE query might solve the issue: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1604538?tag=python&term1=stream&term2=for&term3=loop